# How to: ASP.NET, IIS 7, two sites, same code, one forms auth one not?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis-7, forms-authentication, web-config

Is there any way to have two different IIS sites point at the same code, but only enable forms authentication on one of them?

Some back story, to save your breath 'why the hell do you want to do that?!' type questions...we have inherited a web app that has a major security hole; javascript in the user's browser needs to talk to the service layer directly, and there is *no* security on the service layer whatsoever. Unfortunately the website and service layer are coupled in such a way that they are impossible to seperate without basically rewriting the app. We simply do not have the time to perform the code refactorings nescassary (believe me, we've fought for it)

The user facing part of the website however uses forms auth, so our solution is to share the forms auth ticket between the website and the service layer, as the services live in a virtual directory and so are on the same domain. This works but the problem is that we now need two copies of the application, one with forms auth enabled, and one without, which is a bit of pain for development as we have to constantly update the code in both places.

Comment: I am not sure if I completely grasp your idea but it sounds like that the service layer should not be "auto-protected" by forms authentication. Have you tried to use a "location" tag in web.config for your service layer paths? You could configure that all users are allowed to access a specific path.

Comment: We can't disable invidual services because some of them have methods that are a mix of must-be-secure and must-be-insecure. We can't split these services and have a single 'insecure' service for the must-be-insecure methods because of unbreakable coupling with must-be-secure methods. It's really complicated to explain, and horrible to work with :(

Comment: Honestly.... if everything is so mixed up I wouldn´t introduce a new level of complexity trying to solve both authentication forms. It seems less painful having two destinations to update upon code changes than developing and maintaining increased complexity in a not very well designed architecture.